# How to use Circe to do a dynamic decoding?

Tags: scala, circe

My question is a little tricky. I have a case class looking like this

```
case class Foo(
    id: String,
    name: String,
    field1: Boolean,
    field2: Boolean,
    field3: Boolean,
    field4: Boolean
)
```

However, I have two types of input, one is perfectly fit for the case class `Foo`. The other one is missing values for `field3` and `field4`, looking like
`{id: "Test", name: "Test", field1: true, field2: true}`, I want to create a `Decoder[Foo]` that works for both cases, if the input is missing `field3` and `field4`, just set a default value `false`. Is that possible?

For example,

(1) for the input `{id: "Test", name: "Test", field1: true, field2: true}`, I would like to decode it into

```
Foo("Test, "Test", true, true, false, flase)
```

(2) for the input `{id: "Test", name: "Test", field1: true, field2: true, field3: true, field4: false}`, I would like to decode it into

```
Foo("Test, "Test", true, true, true, flase)
```

I know the best solution is to set `field3` and `field4` as `Option[Boolean]`, however we have a tons of code implemented following the original design and to change the data model will introduce a lot of code change. So just want to see if there is any make shift solution.

thank you very much!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do that. I'm going to assume that you are not going to build codecs from scratch and use what you can get from what there is already in circe.

### Default parameters + generic-extras

There's `circe-generic-extras` package, which allows some customization over automatically derived codecs. In particular, it does allow you to use default parameters as fallback values.

The downside is that it's somewhat slower to compile and also requires you to have an implicit `io.circe.generic.extras.Configuration` in scope.

---

So, first you need that implicit config:

```scala
object Configs {
  implicit val useDefaultValues = Configuration.default.withDefaults
}
```

This usually goes into some generic util package in your project, so you could reuse these configs easily.

Then, you use `@ConfiguredJsonCodec` macro annotation on your class, or use `extras.semiauto.deriveConfiguredCodec` in its companion:

```scala
import Configs.useDefaultValues

@ConfiguredJsonCodec
case class Foo(
    id: String,
    name: String,
    field1: Boolean,
    field2: Boolean,
    field3: Boolean = false,
    field4: Boolean = false
)
```

It's important to not forget a config import, and not have more than one config imported at the same time. Otherwise you will get a not helpful error like

```
could not find Lazy implicit value of type io.circe.generic.extras.codec.ConfiguredAsObjectCodec[Foo]
```

That's enough to decode `Foo` now in case fields that have default values are missing:

```scala
println {
    io.circe.parser.decode[Foo]("""
{
  "id": "someid",
  "name": "Gordon Freeman",
  "field1": false,
  "field2": true
}
""")
  }
```

Self-contained scastie [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/bDtSSut8SzCnTSUlL8WwiA).

### Fallback decoder

The idea is as follows: have a separate case class describing the old format of data, and build a decoder to attempt parsing the data as both old and new formats. Circe decoders have `or` combinator for just that sort of attempting.

---

Here, first you describe the "old" format of data, and a way to upgrade it to a new one:

```scala
@JsonCodec(decodeOnly = true)
case class LegacyFoo(
    id: String,
    name: String,
    field1: Boolean,
    field2: Boolean,
) {
  def upgrade: Foo =
    Foo(id, name, field1, field2, false, false)
}
```

With new format, you have to join the codecs manually, so you can't use macro annotation. Still, you can use `generic.semiauto.deriveXXX` methods to not have to list all the fields yourself:

```scala
case class Foo(
    id: String,
    name: String,
    field1: Boolean,
    field2: Boolean,
    field3: Boolean,
    field4: Boolean
)

object Foo {
  implicit val encoder: Encoder[Foo] = semiauto.deriveEncoder[Foo]
  implicit val decoder: Decoder[Foo] =
    semiauto.deriveDecoder[Foo] or Decoder[LegacyFoo].map(_.upgrade)
}
```

This will also "just work" for the same payload:

```scala
println {
    io.circe.parser.decode[Foo]("""
{
  "id": "someid",
  "name": "Gordon Freeman",
  "field1": false,
  "field2": true
}
""")
}
```

Scastie [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/gVzE5hBBRzadaso3UopWCA).

---

The first approach requires an extra library, but has less boilerplate. It will also allow the caller to supply, e.g. `field4` but not `field3` - in second approach, the value of `field4` will be entirely discarded in that scenario.

The second one allows to handle more complicated changes than "field added with a default values", like computing values out of several others or changing the structure inside a collection, and also to have several more versions should you need them later.

Oh, you can also put `LegacyFoo` into `object Foo`, and make it private if you don't want extra public datatypes exposed.

Answer (score 3):

Won't parameter defaults work for this?

```
case class Foo(id: String
              ,name: String
              ,field1: Boolean
              ,field2: Boolean
              ,field3: Boolean = false
              ,field4: Boolean = false)

Foo("Jo","Josephine",true,true)
//res0: Foo = Foo(Jo,Josephine,true,true,false,false)
```

Comment: I am trying to decode a HTTP response into the `Foo` case class. Even if we set default values to `field3`, if it is missing in the response, Circe will fail to decode with error `Attemp to decode value on failed cursor`